# How to split the string with slash correctly

Tags: java, regex

Code:

```
String line = "/abc/1/";
String[] tokens = line.split("/");
```

I want to get `{"", "abc", "1", ""}`.

However, the actual output is `{"", "abc", "1"}`.

What confuses me is why there is only one "", maybe there is something wrong with `line.split("/")`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the not-often-used second parameter of `String#split`:

```
String line = "/abc/1/";
String[] tokens = line.split("/", -1);
```

This returns `{"", "abc", "1", ""}`.

### Demo

From the documentation for [`String#split(String pattern, int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> If **n** is non-positive then the **pattern** will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length

Answer (score 1):

Just a follow-up to Tim's answer, as the doc clearly points out there is a second `flag` we can use to control the **times of the regex applied** to the string. And there are three different options we have for the `limit`:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

1. If the `limit` n is **positive** then the returned array's length will be no greater than n, and the **array's last entry** will contain all the left.
2. If the `limit` n is **negative** then there is no limit and all the elements that match the pattern will be returned;
3. If the `limit` n is **zero**, then based on the No.2, all the suffixing/trailing empties will be discarded.

So to your problem, you should try:

```
line.split("/", -1); // include all results.
```